# Angular 2 Routing with parameter undefined

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I'm trying to create a route in Angular 2 that takes me to data of a json file, depending on the id. For instance I have 10001.json, 10002.json, 10003.json, etc...

People should be able to get to their patientfile by typing in that particular id as an url, but so far that's not working. I'm actually getting :

***GET http://localhost:4200/assets/backend/patienten/undefined.json 404 (Not Found)***

This is my patientcomponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {PatientService} from "../patient.service";
import {Patient} from "../models";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patient',
  templateUrl: './patient.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient.component.sass']
})
export class PatientComponent implements OnInit {

  patient:Patient[];
  id:any;

  errorMessage:string;

  constructor(private patientService:PatientService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.getData();
    this.id = this.route.params['id'];
    this.patientService.getPatient(this.id)
      .subscribe(patient => this.patient = patient);

  }

  getData() {
    this.patientService.getPatient(this.id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.patient = data;
          console.log(this.patient);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = <any> error);


  }
}
```

This is the routing, very basic:

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {AfdelingComponent} from "./afdeling/afdeling.component";
import {PatientComponent} from "./patient/patient.component";



export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AfdelingComponent},
  {path: 'patient/:id', component: PatientComponent}

];
```

And the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Patient} from "./models";

@Injectable()
export class PatientService {
  private patientUrl = "/assets/backend/patienten/";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPatient(id:any): Observable<Patient[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.patientUrl + id + '.json' )
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

  addPatient(afdelingsNaam: string, afdeling: any): Observable<Patient> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({"afdelingsNaam": afdelingsNaam, afdeling: afdeling});
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(this.patientUrl, body, options)
      .map(res => <Patient> res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call getData before `this.id` is populated.
Just change places

```
ngOnInit():void {
  this.id = this.route.params['id'];
  this.getData();
  this.patientService.getPatient(this.id)
    .subscribe(patient => this.patient = patient);

  }
```

Edited:
route.params is an Observable, so you need to use it like:

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

   // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
});
```

Comment: I've tried that but I get the same error. I do think we're on the right track here, just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Tell me please, why do you need to run `this.patientService.getPatient(this.id)` it twice? First in `getData` and then explicitly

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. I deleted the explicit one.... same mistake still. Thank you for helping me though :)

Comment: Yes! That did it ! Thank you Denis Reshetniak :)

Comment: No problem :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide those files as static assets to your angular app, otherwise the angular router will try route those requests to your in-app routes, which wont have a matching route.

You can do this by editing the 'assets' value in your `angular-cli.json`, and specifying any files and folders you would like to have accessible via your routing. (and also copied by the angular cli to your dist folder during build.)

As an example, the following would copy and allow routing to the following:

- src/assets/* (entire folder)
- src/somefolder/* (entire folder)
- src/favicon.ico
- src/web.config

`"assets": [
        "assets",
        "somefolder",
        "favicon.ico",
        "web.config"
      ],`

For more in depth examples, have a look at the Angular CLI wiki here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not the issue, as I have an other json file in the same folder that I can identify.